# Qual a forma mais eficiente de se ligar um BD Oracle a um BD MySql

Tags: mysql, oracle, pl-sql, integração, oracle11c

Tendo o seguinte cenário: uma aplicação simples de telefonia "escreve" em um BD Mysql e um BD Oracle precisava de tempos em tempos procurar uma informação neste BD MySql.

Alguém já fez isto?

Qual seria a melhor prática?

---

ps Na realidade não podemos unificar pois são produtos de fornecedores diferentes , no Oracle temos alguma capacidade de manobra para fazer esta atualização , que vem a ser : gravar o protocolo do Atendimento (Mysql) em uma tabela do Oracle.

Comment: Eu criaria uma rotina ETL no Oracle para puxar esses dados de tempos em tempos.

Comment: Qual a linguagem disponível para integração? Faça um _webservice_.

Answer (score 0):

A solucao ideal depende de varias perguntas, como versao do Oracle, tamanho das tabelas, complexidade das consultas, frequencia de atualizacao e capacidade tecnica do desenvolvedor. Eh necessario estabelecer essas metricas antes de definir a solucao mais adequada.

Para tabelas relativamente pequenas, eu programaria um *dump* no MySQL, exportando os dados para um CSV em disco. O Oracle consegue ler diretamente o CSV, sem necessidade de importar os dados, atraves de um recurso chamado **tabela externa**.

Como voce disse que a aplicacao eh "simples" e que o Oracle busca dados no MySQL "de tempos em tempos", me parece que a solucao acima eh adequada para uma implementacao simples.

A medida em que o intervalo de tempo encurta e/ou o volume de dados aumenta, a solucao por tabela externa pode ser inadequada. Nesses casos, uma solucao mais adequada seria a ligacao direta entre Oracle e MySQL.

O Oracle tem um recurso chamado "Database Link", que permite a uma database (local) executar comandos SQL sobre outra database (remota). Quando as databases local e remota estao ambas no Oracle, o processo eh bem simples.

Ja quando a database remota esta em outra plataforma (no seu caso, MySQL), eh preciso configurar uma conexao ODBC no servidor local. O Oracle consegue ler dados via ODBC e dessa forma acessar o MySQL em tempo real.

Lembre-se, porem, que conexoes via ODBC nao tem a mesma escalabilidade de conexoes nativas. Novamente, depende do volume de dados e concorrencia das queries.

Comment: Grato pela resposta .Tem um agravante , este "tempos em tempos" é um intervalo curto , na realidade uma aplicação de telefonia escreve no MySql um protocolo , precisamos levar este número para um ERP